# How to save STDERR and STDOUT of a pipeline on a file?

Tags: bash, stdout, pipeline, stderr

I'm running a pipeline of commands that have STDERR and STDOUT outputs. I want to save both outputs in a single log file.

This are my attempts to do it:

```
bash my_script.sh > log.txt   #Only save STDOUT
bash my_script.sh > >(tee log.txt) 2> >(tee log.txt >&2)  #The STDERR overwrite the STDOUT
```

I hope you can provide a simple solution to do this.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just

```
bash my_script.sh > >(tee log.txt) 2>&1
```

Also if you want to append output if log.txt already exists, add -a option to tee

```
bash my_script.sh > >(tee -a log.txt) 2>&1
```

It's actually equivalent to `bash my_script.sh 2>&1 | tee log.txt` or `bash my_script.sh 2>&1 | tee -a log.txt`

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly!. But I still don't understand how the ´tee´ command works. Can you explain it a little bit?

Comment: The tee command save a copy of the input it receives to a file while sending it to the stdout as well. `>(tee log.txt)` creates process substitution that represents itself as a file (try `echo >(:)`) that could be accessed as `bash myscript.sh > generated_named_pipe 2>&1`. So basically you use tee if you want to save your output to a file but still want to see on the screen.

Comment: Or, even shorter: `bash -c myscript.sh |& tee log.txt`

Answer (score 3):

bash my_script.sh > log.txt 2>&1

where 2>&1 redirects stderr to stdout

Comment: It doesn't write anything on log.txt

Comment: You got the order of your redirects backwards, it should be `command > file 2>&1`. See [this page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial#order_of_redirection_ie_file_2_1_vs_2_1_file) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my post instead of deleting it as I prefer the shorter version.

Comment: Now is working, thanks!! But the big advantage of using tee is that you can also watch the output while is printing on the screen.